# Why does perl not allow me to dereference a member of a hash reference into an array?

Tags: arrays, perl

Perl terms confuse me and it's not my native language, so bear with me.  I'll try to use the right terms, but I'll give an example just to make sure.

So I have a hash reference in the variable $foo.  Lets say that $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'} is an array reference.  That is I can get the first member of the array by assigning $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'}->[0] to a scalar.

when I do this:

```
foreach (@$foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'})
{
    #some code that deals with $_
}
```

I get the error "Not an ARRAY reference at script.pl line 41"

But when I do this it works:

```
$myarr = $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'};
foreach (@$myarr)
{
    #some code that deals with $_
}
```

Is there something I'm not understanding?  Is there a way I can get the first example to work?  I tried wrapping the expression in parentheses with the @ on the outside, but that didn't work.  Thanks ahead of time for the help.

Comment: The parser has to understand what you mean, and the syntax you try at the first go things you want to dereference @$foo, which you can't in your case. It's all about how different tokens bind to the things around them. We have a longer explanation in _Intermediate Perl_. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$myarr = $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'};
foreach (@$myarr)
{
    #some code that deals with $_
}
```

If you replace your **`$myarr`** in for loop with its RHS, it looks like:  -

```
foreach (@{$foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'}})
{
    #some code that deals with $_
}
```

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles upon this, the key to this answer is the curly braces that encase the entire expression.  I wish I could mark two answers because the explanation on the precedence issue is also very helpful.

Comment: @JasonThompson Then why don't you mark the answer with the explanation as the correct one?

Comment: Why a down vote on an accepted answer?? Can the downvoter leave a comment here??

Answer (score 14):

It's just a precedence issue.

```
@$foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'}
```

means

```
( ( @{ $foo } )->{'bar'} )->{'baz'}
```

`$foo` does not contain an array reference, thus the error. You don't get the precedence issue if you don't omit the optional curlies around the reference expression.

```
@{ $foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'} }
```

Answer (score 3):

It should look like

```
foreach (@{$foo->{'bar'}->{'baz'}})
{
    #some code that deals with $_
}
```